# Why BETWEEN takes more locks then needed?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 , data TINYINT DEFAULT NULL
 , PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO my_table(id, data) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1);
```

All tests have trx_isolation=READ COMMITTED.
Tested on MySQL 5.7 / MySQL 8

This works as expected, both transactions got locks:

```
-- sess1:
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 5; -- ok
-- sess2:
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id BETWEEN 6 AND 10; -- ok
```

But, if we change the order of statements, we're getting a lock conflict:

```
-- sess1:
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id BETWEEN 6 AND 10; -- ok
-- sess2:
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 5; -- waiting for the lock on id=6
```

My question is, why would mysql try to get the id=6 lock is sess2. It's more then needed.

[image]

Comment: See [innodb locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locks-set.html), specifically the part: *"For other search conditions, and for non-unique indexes, InnoDB locks the index range scanned, using gap locks or next-key locks to block insertions by other sessions into the gaps covered by the range. For information about gap locks and next-key locks, see Section 14.7.1, “InnoDB Locking”."*

Comment: And the sections "Gaps locks" and "Next-key locks" in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking.html

Comment: Docs don't explain this, I have not found the answer

Comment: 6 is the next key after 5, isn't it?

Comment: "A next-key lock is a combination of a record lock on the index record and a gap lock on the gap before the index record."
Here is the definition from docs.

Comment: "6 is the next key after 5, isn't it?" 6 goes after 5, that's correct. But what your comment has to do with my question I dont understand :) If you mean next key lock, it's a lock on the gap BEFORE the index record. So my index record is 5. The gap BEFORE 5 is (4, 5].

Comment: Yeah, but your first transaction has already got locks for keys 6 to 10. That includes the key before 6, so 5.

Comment: 5 is not an issue, as you can see from the screenshot, sess1 has granted the lock on id=5. And on top of that, it tries to get the lock on id=6.

Comment: I gave up long ago on figuring this out.  When I see that two ranges are "next" to each other, I assume there is a _chance_ of an unnecessary blockage.  You seem to have found an excellent example of inconsistency.

Comment: I also have no idea why these ranges should overlap in locks. I just remember the former Director of Engineering for MySQL telling me, "there is no person on Earth who understands all of InnoDB's locking behavior."